# Why I am receiving only a few audio samples per second when using AVAssetReader on iOS?

Tags: ios, audio, avfoundation, avassetwriter, avassetreader

I'm coding something that:

- record video+audio with the built-in camera and mic (AVCaptureSession),
- do some stuff with the video and audio samplebuffer in realtime,
- save the result into a local .mp4 file using AVAssetWritter,
- then (later) read the file (video+audio) using AVAssetReader,
- do some other stuff with the samplebuffer (for now I do nothing),
- and write the result into a final video file using AVAssetWriter.

Everything works well but I have an issue with the audio format:

When I capture the audio samples from the capture session, I can log about 44 samples/sec, which seams to be normal. 
When I read the .mp4 file, I only log about 3-5 audio samples/sec! 
But the 2 files look and sound exactly the same (in QuickTime).

- I didn't set any audio settings for the Capture Session (as Apple doesn't allow it).
- I configured the outputSettings of the 2 audio AVAssetWriterInput as follow:

  ```
  NSDictionary *settings = @{
      AVFormatIDKey:@(kAudioFormatLinearPCM),
      AVNumberOfChannelsKey:@(2),
      AVSampleRateKey:@(44100.),
      AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey:@(16),
      AVLinearPCMIsNonInterleaved:@(NO),
      AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey:@(NO),
      AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey:@(NO)
  };
  ```
- I pass nil to the outputSettings of the audio AVAssetReaderTrackOutput in order to receive samples as stored in the track (according to the doc).

**So, the sample rate should be 44100Hz from the CaptureSession to the final file. Why I am reading only a few audio samples?  And why is it working anyway? I have the intuition that it will not work well when I'll have to work with the samples (I need to update their timestamps for example).**

I tried several other settings (such as kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC), but AVAssetReader can't read compressed audio formats.

Thanks for your help :)